# Variable not assign using asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

This is a part of my view code :

```
<%int imageTypSelected = 0; %>  



<div class="imageToEdit" >
         <img src='<%: Url.Action("getImg", "Product", new{ShopId = Model.Id}) %>'   alt="" />
         <a href="#" id="1" onclick="jQuery('#dialog').dialog('open'); '<%:imageTypSelected=1 %>'; return false;  ">G</a>             
    </div>

    <div   >
         <img src='<%: Url.Action("getImg_Alt1", "Product", new{ShopId = Model.Id}) %>'   alt="" />
         <a href="#" id="2"  onclick="jQuery('#dialog').dialog('open'); '<%:imageTypSelected=2 %>'; return false; " >G</a>           
    </div>

    <div  >
         <img src='<%: Url.Action("getImg_Alt2", "Product", new{ShopId = Model.Id}) %>'   alt="" />
         <a href="#" id="3"  onclick="jQuery('#dialog').dialog('open'); '<%:imageTypSelected=3 %>'; return false; ">G</a>            
    </div>



 <div id="dialog" title="A" >
          <% using (Html.BeginForm("changeProductImage", "Product", new { @Id = Model.Id, @selectedHyperLink = imageTypSelected }, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
               {%>
                <p><input type="file" id="fileUpload" name="fileUpload" style="width:23;"/> </p>
                <p><input type="submit" value="B" /></p>
          <% } %>

       </div>
```

By Clicking on first  the variable `imageTypSelected` must set to 1. By second must set to 3 and by clicking third it must be set to 3. Then this variable post to a method in controller. But all the time only the value `3` is assigned to variable and clicking on other  does not effect on variable. what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing up server-side code and client-side code.

`imageTypSelected` only exists on the server. It's not going to get changed when you click the links in the browser. You need to do this completely in javascript:

Remove this from your form:

```
@selectedHyperLink = imageTypSelected
```

and add this hidden field:

```
<input type="hidden" id="selectedhyperlink" name="selectedhyperlink" />
```

Add this javascript function which will set the hidden field to the correct value:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeImageType(imageType) {
        jQuery("#selectedhyperlink").val(imageType);
        jQuery("#dialog").dialog("open");

        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Call this function from your links:

```
<a href="#" id="2" onclick="return changeImageType(2);">G</a>
```